# Can not write to internal storage on Nexus 4

Tags: internal-storage, file-management, mtp

I connect the Nexus 4 to the computer (Win7), and go Computer\Nexus 4\Internal storage. I can copy **from** it, I can create folders, but I can not copy data to it.

I had the previous one replaced because of a faulty touch screen, I was able to copy things both ways without problem on that one. The computer I use is the same.

I can copy files onto it with ftp. Does not matter if it is the client or the server in this case.

I can also copy files if I turn on USB debugging.

How can I fix this?